# Reading char from file and writing to another file

Tags: c++, arrays

I am quite new in c++ and programming so sorry in advance in my question repeats. I have a text file of 3 lines:

```
7
```

00000000000000000000000*0000

0 0 0 R 0

What I need to do is read 2nd line and write it into an array as char. But I must not include 3rd line because it will go to a completely different matrix. My code so far :

```
ifstream input;
input.open("input1.txt");
input >> start;
char a=0;
string line;
while (getline(input, line))
{
    a=0;
    istringstream iss(line);
    int length = line.size();
    for (int i=0; i<length; i++)
    {
        iss >> a;
        A[i] = a;
        cout << A[i] << " " << i << endl;
    }
}
input.close();
```

However, with this code it always starts new array for 3rd line. What am I doing wrong? What is the easiest way to fix it? Thank you.

-----------------------------Update--------------------------------------

I have modified the code but it still does not work properly. I am getting this kind of result : 5)-└ instead of correct one. My current code:

```
void Read(int &numLines, int &start, vector<char>&A, char B[][5])
{
ifstream input;
input.open("input.txt");
input >> start;
input.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
string line;
if(getline(input, line))
{
    for(char temp: line)
    {
        A.push_back(temp);
    }
}
input.close();
```

}

`A` here is a vector I want to write 2nd line to, char by char
`Start` is just an integer in which I am storing 1st line (7)

Thank you very much for advices

Comment: What do you mean "starts new array"? What is `A`? Where is your [MCVE]?

Comment: Since your `while` loop keeps reading until end of file is encounted, parsing each line into the `A` array, it logically follows that the `A` array will end up having the parsed contents of the last line in the file.

Comment: Is reading the first line into an `int` a requirement too?

Answer (score 0):

Mixing `>>` and `std::getline` is non-trivial. For example, after `input >> start;` the end of line marker is left in the stream in case it's still needed. In your case it isn't, and it is picked off by the subsequent call to `getline`, resulting in a read of an empty line.

This is what's complicating your read of `line` and forcing the `while` loop and test for empty lines.

Step through your program with your [development environment's debugger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debugger) and you'll see what I'm talking about. Get used to using the debugger. It's possibly the best programming productivity tool you'll ever encounter.

The easiest way to fix it is to place

```
input.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```

after

```
input >> start;
```

to eat up the end of the line (and anything else that might be on that line. This needs the addition of `#include<limits>` to get `std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max`.

Then you can remove the while loop and replace it with

```
if (getline(input, line))
```

No loop, not chance of consuming multiple lines from the file. And the logic for reading and processing the third line can follow.

Side note: instead of that `for` loop, consider

```
int i = 0;
while (iss >> a)
{
    A[i] = a;
    cout << A[i] << " " << i << endl;
    i++;
}
```

This will march through `iss` until it hits the end of the line. You can also throw `iss` out entirely and just read the characters directly out of `line`.

```
int i = 0;
for(char temp: line)
{
    A[i] = temp;
}
```

And `A` should probably be a `vector` if it isn't already to reduce the chances of buffer overruns.

```
for(char temp: line)
{
    A.push_back(temp);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for explanations and advice! I have updated my code(and post with it) but it still does not work. One input file leads to very strange result and other crashes program totally. Would you mind taking a look at whats wrong?

Comment: @A.Black 2 recommendations: 1. It is generally better to ask a new question than add on to an old one. People who possibly would answer the new question have likely read this question and won't read it again to see the update. 2. More information is needed. We see one function and are told the program crashes. But crashes where? Don't know, can't answer. You will need to produce a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

I would go with something like this:

```
std::string start;
std::string Astring;
ifstream input;
input.open("input.txt");
input >> start;
input >> Astring;

// If you really want a char array
char * A = new char[Astring.size()];
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < Astring.size(); i++) {
    A[i] = Astring[i];
}
// Don't forget to delete after use
delete[] A;
```

Moreover, if you just need the char array as an input to something else later, you can call `Astring.c_str()` instead of that `for` loop, which returns a C-style char array.

Comment: Oh yeah, wrote that quick. I'll fix that. Thanks for pointing it out!